# How do you detect the windows phone 7/8 device brand version programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I know how to get the OS version, but I'm looking for something that can tell me what the device is (brand, version, etc). Example: Nokia Lumia 920 Anything close to it will be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mango's [DeviceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394037%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class to get information about the device.

```cs
MessageBox.Show(DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer + " " + DeviceStatus.DeviceName);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [DeviceExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class, the `DeviceManufacturer` and `DeviceName` properties.